# Debian 9 User in sudo group but still unable to issue sudo command

Tags: debian, sudo

User is in the `sudo` group

`/etc/sudoers` file does have an entry

```
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

But they still get the message:

> user not in sudoers file. This incident will be reported.

Comment: Have the user type the `groups` command and see (show in the Question) if it contains “sudo”. Perhaps they logged in before being added to the group.

Answer (score 5):

If you've just added the user to the sudo group, you need a fresh login into the OS. So you may log out and then log back again. Or you can use another tty to do the sudo task without logging in. (Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1...F8</kbd>.)

If you only guess the user is in the group, while in fact it is not, you need to run these two commands:

```
su root
```

And now as root:

```
adduser user_name sudo
```

And now relog or log into another tty.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my "problem", which drove me nuts. <3

Comment: user147505: "And now relog or log into another tty !"

Answer (score 3):

```shell
sudo -l
```

should show you the commands you may and may not execute.  You can add another `-l` for longer output, and specify a user with `-U`:

```shellsession
$ sudo -ll -U myuser
Matching Defaults entries for myuser on myserver:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin, use_pty

User myuser may run the following commands on myserver:

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    RunAsGroups: ALL
    Commands:
    ALL
```